# ¿Cómo generar un único texto de error y que no se repita por string?

Tags: c++

Tengo este código hecho, sin embargo cuando llega al mensaje de error lo que sucede es que manda un mensaje de error por cada cadena *string* que hay, mi cadena `string miarreglo[10]`  tiene 10 variables por lo tanto mi mensaje de error se repite las 10 veces que están marcadas en el *string* y yo solo quiero que se mande una sola vez, no encuentro forma de evitar esta situación, les agradecería mucho si pudiesen ayudarme a completar el código

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int i, elemento;
    string miarreglo[10], j;
    
    cout<<"hola mundo."<<endl;
    cout<<"programa que captura 10 letras, los guarda en un arreglo y muestra en que arreglo esta.\n"<<endl;
    
    do
    {
        cout<<"Ingrese 10 letras."<<endl;
        for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            cout<<"numero "<<i+1<<": ";
            cin>>miarreglo[i];
        }

        while ("true")
        {
            cout<<"los elementos del arreglo son:";
            for(i=0; i<10; i++)
            {
                cout<<miarreglo[i]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        
            cout<<"que numero desea encontrar en el arreglo?";
            cin>>j;
            cout<<endl;
            for(i=0; i<10; i++)
            {
               if(miarreglo[i]==j)
                {
                    elemento=i;
                    cout<<"el elemento se encuentra en la posicion: "<<elemento+1<<endl;
                    getch();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout<<"el elemento es erroneo intenta de nuevo"<<endl;// aqui se repite el error mandado
                    getch();
                    system("cls");
                }   
            } 
            break;  
        }
        getch();
        system("cls");
       
    }while ("true");
  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Si bien `"true"` y cualquier otra cadena se evalúa como `true`, deberías usar la palabra clave `true` y `false`.

Comment: Podrías hacer el código más legible si crearas algunas funciones. En especial una para la búsqueda.

Answer (score 1):

El código es un poco confuso ... pero creo que te basta con eliminar el `else` y poner una condición después del `for`:

```
for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    if( miarreglo[i] == j ) {
        elemento = i;
        cout << "el elemento se encuentra en la posicion: " << elemento + 1 << endl;
        break;
    }
}

if( i == 10 ) {
    cout << "el elemento es erroneo intenta de nuevo" << endl;
}

break;
```

Tu bucle se repite **mientras** `i < 10`. Si en alguna operación interna haces un `break`, sales del bucle con la variable `i` manteniendo su valor, que será **inferior** a `10`.

Si fuera del bucle `i == 10`, es porque no se ha realizado un `break`. Es decir, el bucle ha llegado a la condición *de corte* sin haber encontrado el valor buscado.